# No shaitan no worry 

Tags: shaitan, waswasa, shahada

Assalamualaikum

I was born muslim ,and now i met 'wiswas' problem. I can't digest it which one was a whisper or my mind. And i always feels like whatever i have thought was made me left islam unknowingly!!!! Sometimes I'm sure I didn't doing anything wrong but i feel myself always carrying a lot of sin  because i always have dirty thought about religion , god  and then i feel guilty after i think it. And i feel like I'm not muslim anymore . So i keep taking shahada many many times because i don't want to left islam unknowingly!!! Always make me doubt when i was praying "will my prayer is valid or I'm already in state of kafir" Is it the best way for me to keep taking shahada many times? I can start my islam life after taken shahada or not? Even my feelings always the same everytime because i believe in allah and his prophet pbuh and whatever since first. Is there anyone have a better idea to deal with wiswas? Or at least way to make me calm . I'm really afraid if later i will die when i left islam unknowingly i don't want to go jahannam!!! Please help me and jazakallah. I'm soon crazy

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to tell you a way to be safeguarded against the devil:

> Abu Hurairah (May Allah be pleased with him) reported:
> The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said, "He who utters a hundred times in a day these words: 'La ilaha illallahu, wahdahu la sharika lahu, lahul-mulku wa lahul-hamdu, wa Huwa 'ala kulli sha'in Qadir (there is no true god except Allah. He is One and He has no partner with Him; His is the sovereignty and His is the praise, and He is Omnipotent),' he will have a reward equivalent to that for emancipating ten slaves, a hundred good deeds will be recorded to his credit, hundred of his sins will be blotted out from his scroll, and he will be safeguarded against the devil on that day till the evening; and no one will exceed him in doing more excellent good deeds except someone who has recited these words more often than him. [Source for the hadith](https://sunnah.com/riyadussalihin:1410)

> The Dua - "La ilaha illallahu, wahdahu la sharika lahu, lahul-mulku wa lahul-hamdu, wa Huwa 'ala kulli sha'in Qadir" in Arabic is as per as follows:
>
> > لا إله إلا الله وحده لا شريك له، له الملك، وله الحمد، وهو على كل شيء قدير

Now coming to your whispers which you have said could be from the Shaytan (Devil), Kufr is disbelief in Allah and his Messenger (SAW). So if you have disbelieved in Allah and his Messenger (SAW) then you have committed Kufr.

> Ibn Hazam said in his book al-Fisal:
> “Rejecting something for which there is sound proof that there can be no faith without believing in it is kufr, and uttering words for which there is proof that uttering them is kufr is kufr. Doing any action for which there is proof that it is kufr is also kufr.” [Click here for the source webpage](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21249/what-is-kufr-and-what-are-its-various-kinds#:~:text=Kufr%20may%20also%20take%20the,to%20someone%20other%20than%20Allah.)

Sins are not necessarily kufr. Doing something haram is not necessarily kufr. But there are somethings which can be classified as kufr. I suggest you read this page to get a better understanding: [Click here](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/21249/what-is-kufr-and-what-are-its-various-kinds#:~:text=Kufr%20may%20also%20take%20the,to%20someone%20other%20than%20Allah.)

And Allah knows best, and I too make mistakes.

May Allah guide us all to the truth, and safeguard us against the Shaytan. Ameen.

Answer (score 0):

Wa Alikkum wa salaam

More we try to suppress thoughts, it can come more in our mind. You fear what if bad thoughts about Allah, religion or something you love comes to your mind , wouldn't Allah punish you for the thoughts. So you try to suppress these thoughts but it only increases and you feel guilty. It become a vicious cycle. So the solution to the problem is don't care about what you think but care about what you are doing. Just think whether you are performing five daily prayers on time, how is your relation with others ? are they according to what Islam prescribes ? You can have all type of thoughts in your mind but what is deciding on what you actually believe is the actions that you are performing. So just ignore the bad thoughts and don't take over strain to avoid them, it will go away or reduce.

Always pray to Allah to make yourself firm in religion

> Anas said, "The Prophet, may Allah bless him and grant him peace, most
> frequently said, "O Allah, O Overturner of hearts, make my heart firm
> in Your religion." https://sunnah.com/adab:683

Also, you should understand that your guilt feeling is itself proof that you don't approve of those bad thoughts. If you are really bad, you will never feel guilty. So just ignore the bad thoughts and focus on doing good deeds. InshaAllah, you will be ok.